# Implement SSO using IdentityServer4

Tags: single-sign-on, identityserver4

I was implement the Identity management server by help of the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html).

I am running the  following applications:

1. I run the Identity server
2. I run the API
3. I run the MVC client

My MVC client gets opened in a Chrome browser. After open I click on Login and provide username and password and click submit. I got successfully logged in and it redirects me to the home page.

The problem is, after I open open another Chrome window, then I try to open the MVC Client and it asks me again to login. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the MVC client from the Visual Studio debugger, it creates a brand new browser session (no old cookies, application data etc.). As IdentityServer is keeping the logged user information in a cookie, by running your application like this, you are loosing this cookie, and this is why you are forced to re-login.

I recommend you to deploy your MVC client to a local IIS site and try again. You will see that no such issue occurs (as long as you are not opening the site in an incognito mode of course).

Comment: thank you very much for your valibale help, I try this and update the answer status

Comment: Thanks for the help